# Can plasmodial slime molds be infected by virus?

Tags: virology, infection, eukaryotic-cells

According to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold#Plasmodia), plasmodial slime mold consist of a "single cell" with thousands of nuclei. How would such a unique type of cell response to viral infection (if any)? Google search yield nothing.

Comment: since all known cells are vulnerable to viruses I'm gonna guess yes. and slime molds are only "a single cell" in the same sense fungi are which also have multi-nucleated cells.

Comment: Why do you think having multiple nuclei would have an effect on viral infection? The motivation for your question is unclear to me.